# How to reload a specific service in java?

Tags: java

How can I reload just specific `.class` without having to restart the entire program? Is it possible to achieve that using `public void reload ()`? If it is, then how am I going to declare that? I want to restart my .class files (service.class) using `service.getinstance ().reload()` as trigger if possible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “reload” and “restart”?  Do you mean the same thing?  What thing?

Comment: I believe what you're asking about is called "hotswapping".

Comment: use java ClassLoader for loading class

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load a new implementation of a class that you've previously loaded, you'll need to create a new ClassLoader which will find the new implementation and request the Class and/or object instance through that. Note that this will *NOT* change any of the instances of the class already in use. Tutorials for ClassLoader exist on the web; I'll refer you to them for details.

If you want to modify the class behind objects that *are* active... that's hot-swapping. Not all JVMs support it, and it has limitations in what changes can be made (nothing that changes function signatures, for example). It's really intended for use by interactive debugging tools, where being able to modify a line of code and immediately test the new version in context is important... and where its fragility isn't a problem because if the swap can't be made all that's lost is developer convenience, not end-user data. Generally, if you think you need hot-swapping in anything but a debugging environment, you're wrong.

Comment: Thx for all of your response. I just want my service.class instance to reload or restart that service. No modifications to that class. I'll check classloader as suggested.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Restarting a service should not require changing the code at all. That just requires resetting the service code...