# Programmatic reloading of Java JARs without restarting ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

## Background

From ColdFusion 10 onward it is possible to [include JARs from a custom location](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html).

To load custom Java libraries (or .java files) code similar to the following is added to Application.cfc

```
this.javaSettings = {LoadPaths = [".\java_lib\",".\java\myjar.jar"],
      loadColdFusionClassPath = true, reloadOnChange = false}
```

Or to pickup changes (with a default 60 second refresh time) the following is added

```
this.javaSettings = {LoadPaths = [".\java_lib\",".\java\myjar.jar"], 
         loadColdFusionClassPath = true, reloadOnChange = true}
```

## Question

For development the second option is good (probably with a much lower refresh time). For production the first option would be ideal, but restarting the server every time we need to change any java code is not acceptable. Is there any way to trigger a reload of java classes (preferably programmatic) without restarting the server when `reloadOnChange = false` is set?

Comment: *restarting the server every time we need to change any java code* I am not 100% positive, but ... IIRC it should only require restarting the application, not the whole server. Did you try it? (I realize that is not as granular as you are looking for, but AFAIK CF does not expose any methods for reloading on demand.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using this instead:

https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader

Comment: If it comes to it I may do that, although it's slightly damning of the CF10 functionality if it still can't really be used in production

Comment: @RichardTingle - I am not sure it is as simple as we may be thinking ... .. Given that it involves dynamic class loaders, there may be [some technical limitations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26189233/104223) involved, depending on the implementation.  RE: JavaLoader.cfc - Last I checked it was recommended the JavaLoader be stored in the server scope to avoid [memory leaks with URLClassLoaders](http://www.compoundtheory.com/using-a-java-urlclassloader-in-cfmx-can-cause-a-memory-leak/).  Not sure how/if the issue relates to the CF10 feature as well (since it uses dynamic class loaders too).